# How to Manage MongoDB Client across Packages in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am currently starting out with `MongoDB` on `GoLang`. My current use case is this.

I wish to initialize connection to my `MongoDB Database` in a particular package and use the returned `client` across several other local packages. Here is what I have tried,

I have initialized the connection to `MongoDB` inside a package called `dataLayer` as below

```
package dataLayer

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

func InitDataLayer() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(credentials.MONGO_DB_ATLAS_URI))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Connected to Database")
    }
}
```

Now if I wish to use the returned `client` in other packages, is it production safe to keep on calling `initDataLayer` over and over again to get back a `client`?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have to call `InitDataLayer` over and over again. You need to create only one client, you can use the same client to connect to Mongo DB from various places.

Mongo client internally maintains a pool of connections, so you don't have to create this client again and again.

It's a good design to store this client as the struct field and keep reusing the same.

Edit:

Create Connection

```golang
package dataLayer

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

func InitDataLayer()(*mongo.Client) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(credentials.MONGO_DB_ATLAS_URI))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Connected to Database")
    }
    return client
}
```

---

main.go,

Close connection at the end of usage, otherwise connection would be leaked.

```golang
func main(){
   //...
   client = dataLayer.InitDataLayer()
   defer client.Disconnect(context.Background())
   ...
}
```

---

Repository/DAL, store client in Repository struct

Interface

```
type BookRepository interface {
   FindById( ctx context.Context, id int) (*Book, error)
}
```

Repository Implementation that store client in struct

```golang
type bookRepository struct {
  client *mongo.Client
}

func (r *bookRepository) FindById( ctx context.Context, id int) (*Book, error) {
  var book  Book
  err := r.client.DefaultDatabase().Collection("books").FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": id }).Decode(&book)
  
  if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
    return nil, nil
  }
  if err != nil  {
     return nil, err
  }
  return &book, nil
}
```

Comment: @sonus21.Thanks for your response. Can you show an example?

Comment: You can use a concept of Dependency Injection.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: @Misti That's true, but Go does not have the full support of dependency injection. Though people have created libraries for DI, we would need a DI that should support cleanup as well, at the same it should not create too many instances of Client.

Comment: what about the context, should it be in the Repository struct?

Comment: @DenCowboy not at all,  context is dynamic, it's meant for each call. So it should be passed as function parameter.